# Include html based on li tag's id in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a script that I want to include a html file based on the list item's id.

I've got two list items

```
<ul class="fruits">
         <li id="0">Apples</li>
         <li id="1">Pears</li>
</ul>
```

Now here's my script so far. Basically I want to check the `id` of the selected list item and insert a html file with a description of that fruit.

Script is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fruits li").click(function() {
                if(this.id == "0") {
                    $(".fruit_copy").load("blocktext/apple.html");
                }
        });
});
```

And I want this `<div class="fruit_copy"> </div>` to be populated with the `HTML` content. But of course it's not working.

Comment: `class=".fruit_copy"` is not valid, I think you meant to put `class="fruit_copy"` (simple revision)

Comment: sorry that's a typo based on this question! The div is `class="fruit_copy"` in reality. Will edit this now.

Comment: did you check console...? Does .load() fetch relevant content..?

Comment: "Not working" isn't a sufficient description of the problem.

Comment: @cookiemonster it doesn't display in the allotted space for the `fruit_copy` division.

Comment: Is the path to the html correct?

Comment: You're using a relative URL, is that what you intend? What debugging have you done?

Comment: yes the directory `blocktext` and my `PHP` file are in the same directory.

Comment: I think you can't use numbers as ID. In CSS it doesn't work, so try other IDs ?

Comment: script is working for me. there must be something wrong with your selector `.fruit_copy` or the document (path) you are trying to load.

Comment: @enguerranws HTML5 doesn't care about an ID starting with a number but  HTML4 does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: Yep, but it still doesn't work on many browsers...

Comment: @enguerranws Do you have a source on that? I tried this in the latest IE , Chrome, and Firefox without any problems. I even tried it in IE8 and it worked! http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/html5-id (click the top link on that page to switch from classes to ids and vice versa)

Comment: I said "In CSS it doesn't work" : http://jsfiddle.net/M4YUu/ . Sure JS doesn't matter, but why would you name an element you can't handle with CSS if you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something cleaner, like that :

HTML part :

```
<ul class="fruits">
         <li data-dest="blocktext/apple.html">Apples</li>
         <li data-dest="blocktext/pears.html" >Pears</li>
</ul>
```

JS part :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fruits li").click(function() {
     // you don't need IDs or if/else statement.
     var dest = $(this).attr('data-dest');
     $(".fruit_copy").load(dest);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".fruits li").click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "0") {
        //alert("aa");
        $(".fruit_copy").load("blocktext/apple.html");
    }
    });
});
```

Assuming your relative path is correct.

Also, in `HTML 5` you can use ID's as numbers but `HTML 4` is strict on it.

**EDIT - Thanks to MiniRagnarok for the link in comments**

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/3739658

**For HTML 4, the answer is technically:**

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: I like the idea of your code. Just to check should this JS be at the top of my html document (i.e. in the `head` tags or at the bottom before closing the `body`).

Comment: bottom or you could embed it using an external .js file :) Needs to be at the bottom so the HTML attributes are declared

Comment: @user3739658 Feel free to add my source about IDs as numbers to your answer.

Comment: Done with yours and orignal authors comments ofcourse

Comment: Well, you can put it wherever you want, after jQuery "$" is declared. $(document).ready() means that it will wait for the whole document to be ready, so... whatever.

Answer (score 0):

- The options values are "falsey", they're strings whilst you're checking integers, help it by adding `.toString()`:

We also append the `===` so we're not type checking - string to string.

```
if ( this.id.toString() === "0" ) {
   //Code
}
```

- Lastly, check your console & use the network tab to see if your script is successfully collecting the `.html` file with a `200` HTTP code.

Comment: $('.fruits li') are not newly loaded elements. But well, this answer is somewhat complete, so it does not deserve a downvote...

Comment: @enguerranws Ah aye, overlooked that aspect, I'll edit that part out - thanks for noting :) But it's hardly a full answer as I would like it to be now ;)